# Open source face swapping Android app

Tags: android, open-source, photography, camera, face-recognition

There are many face swap apps, but are there open source ones?

[image: face swap]

Requirements:

- Open source
- Takes image from device's camera
- Must be real time, at least real time preview
- The most accurate the swap the better. After that, the most user-friendly the better